# Fetching images from url with hash maps , doesn't display them

Tags: java, android

Beginner at android app development here and i am making a game news app which shows alot of games(items) in recycler view grid.
Everything is displayed right except the images from url.
Here is some of my code:

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSource;

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
protected HomeItemAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);


    initDataset();


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new HomeItemAdapter(this, mDataSource);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}


private void initDataset() {
    mDataSource = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap();
    h1.put("name", "Super Meat Boy");
    h1.put("city", "Indie");
    h1.put("image_url","https://66.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ldi4d79gyD1qd9jlto1_500.jpg");
    mDataSource.add(h1);
```

HomeItemAdapter.java

```
public class HomeItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "NTR-HomeItemAdapter";


public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSource;
private Context mContext;

public HomeItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mDataSource) {
    this.mDataSource = mDataSource;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_home_item, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Target target;
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    viewHolder.getName().setText(mDataSource.get(position).get("name"));
    viewHolder.getCity().setText(mDataSource.get(position).get("city"));

    //Get Marquee
    viewHolder.getName().setSingleLine();
    viewHolder.getName().setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    viewHolder.getName().setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    viewHolder.getName().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    viewHolder.getName().setSelected(true);
    viewHolder.getName().setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

    viewHolder.getCity().setSingleLine();
    viewHolder.getCity().setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    viewHolder.getCity().setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    viewHolder.getCity().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    viewHolder.getCity().setSelected(true);
    viewHolder.getCity().setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

    // Get Dynamic Color
    target = new com.squareup.picasso.Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    if (palette !=null) {
                        viewHolder.getImageCover().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Palette.Swatch vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                        if(vibrant!=null) {
                            viewHolder.getCardItemHome().setBackgroundColor(vibrant.getRgb());
                            viewHolder.getName().setTextColor(vibrant.getTitleTextColor());
                            viewHolder.getCity().setTextColor(vibrant.getTitleTextColor());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            viewHolder.getImageCover().setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };
    Log.d(TAG,mDataSource.get(position).get("image_url"));

    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(mDataSource.get(position).get("image_url"))
            .into(target);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final CardView cardItemHome;
    private final ImageView imgCover;
    private final TextView txtName;
    private final TextView txtCity;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getPosition() + " clicked.");
            }
        });
        cardItemHome = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_item_home);
        txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txtCity = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_city);
        imgCover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_cover);

    }

    public CardView getCardItemHome() {
        return cardItemHome;
    }

    public TextView getName() {
        return txtName;
    }

    public TextView getCity() {
        return txtCity;
    }

    public ImageView getImageCover() {
        return imgCover;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: is your Log showing the right Image URL?

Comment: @Theo Yes it is the right one . I have put internet permission aswell.

Comment: Is the target an ImageView? I am going over Picasso now. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: It looks quite straightforward.

Comment: @Theo Really weird, while i was trying it just know one item in my recycler view displayed an image and the next time i tried it , it was gone.No luck on images in other items though.

Comment: It looks like a very simple thing that you are missing. Saying from experience. Just keep on playing with it and go over the Picasso documentation again. You should manage to get it right. If not let me know I will take a look a bit later. GL!

Comment: @Theo Thanks alot Theo! And you were right it was a simple thing missing .... I resized and center cropped the downloaded images from url and they display just fine!

Comment: Glad that I could help! You kind of done it yourself anyway.